# Backbone - file-like application root

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing, relative-url

If I am serving my Backbone application from http://example.com/foo/bar.html, what should I specify the application root as? E.g.:

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/foo/'
});
```

vs

```
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    root: '/foo/bar.html'
});
```

In fact, does it even matter as far as Backbone routing and history are concerned?

I notice that if I use the former form, images with relative URLs become broken because `pushState` would cause the (apparent) location of the window to change to a string like `/foo/login`, and then a relative URL like `img/orange_cat.jpg` gets resolved to `/foo/login/img/orange_cat.jpg` by the browser, when I really want `/foo/img/orange_cat.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

The first form is the correct one.

### To fix the broken images issue

And add this to your head tag

```
<base href="/foo/" />
```